# Excel like vlookup using python pandas with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vlookup

I need to perform vlookup on dataframe using python/pandas like in Excel with some conditions.

**Condition:-**

1. I need to create a one new  column (DFM) in my 2nd DataFrame using Excel like vlookup.
2. If DFM value is na then print 100% in 2nd Dataframe's DFM. Like in below result data.
3. In result data DFM column I need to apply vlookup for first 10 rows only. Then from 11th row I want to copy first 10 rows data again and again but after dropping first row every time. Please look at the result example below. As we will drop first row on every iteration we will have empty last row so we need to print 100% there as given in condition 2.

1st DataFrame:-

```
  S.No     Cal     Date             DFM
  1            8       01-03-2013   100.00%
  1            7       01-06-2013   100.00%
  1            6       01-09-2013   100.00%
  1            5       01-12-2013   99.99%
  1            4       01-03-2014   99.97%
  1            3       01-06-2014   99.95%
  1            2       01-09-2014   98.89%
  1            1      01-12-2014   39.36%
  1            0      01-03-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-06-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-09-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-12-2015   0.00%
  1            8      01-03-2013   100.00%
  1            7      01-06-2013   100.00%
  1            6      01-09-2013   100.00%
  1            5      01-12-2013   99.99%
  1            4      01-03-2014   99.97%
  1            3      01-06-2014   99.95%
  1            2      01-09-2014   98.89%
  1            1      01-12-2014   39.36%
  1            0      01-03-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-06-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-09-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-12-2015   0.00%
  1            8      01-03-2013   100.00%
  1            7      01-06-2013   100.00%
  1            6      01-09-2013   100.00%
  1            5      01-12-2013   99.99%
  1            4      01-03-2014   99.97%
  1            3      01-06-2014   99.95%
  1            2      01-09-2014   98.89%
  1            1      01-12-2014   39.36%
  1            0      01-03-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-06-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-09-2015   0.00%
  1            0      01-12-2015   0.00%
```

2nd DataFrame:-

```
      Cal     Group        
        1     period 1    
        2     period 1    
        3     period 1    
        4     period 1   
        5     period 1    
        6     period 1    
        7     period 1    
        8     period 1    
        9     period 1    
       10    period 1         
        1     period 1    
        2     period 1    
        3     period 1    
        4     period 1   
        5     period 1    
        6     period 1    
        7     period 1    
        8     period 1    
        9     period 1    
       10    period 1        
        1     period 1    
        2     period 1    
        3     period 1    
        4     period 1   
        5     period 1    
        6     period 1    
        7     period 1    
        8     period 1    
        9     period 1    
       10    period 1
```

Result:-

```
        Cal     Group       DFM
         1     period 1    39.36%
         2     period 1    98.89
         3     period 1    99.95%
         4     period 1    99.97%
         5     period 1    99.99%
         6     period 1    100.00%
         7     period 1    100.00%
         8     period 1    100.00%
         9     period 1    100.00%
        10    period 1    100.00%
         1      period 1    98.89
         2     period 1    99.95%
         3     period 1    99.97%
         4     period 1    99.99%
         5     period 1    100.00%
         6     period 1    100.00%
         7     period 1    100.00%
         8     period 1    100.00%
         9     period 1    100.00%
        10    period 1    100.00%
         1     period 1    99.95%
         2     period 1    99.97%
         3     period 1    99.99%
         4     period 1    100.00%
         5     period 1    100.00%
         6     period 1    100.00%
         7     period 1    100.00%
         8    period 1    100.00%
         9    period 1    100.00%
        10    period 1    100.00%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many programming languages the equivalent of vlookups is some implenation of [SQL joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). In pandas that's either [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for columns or [`df.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for indexes.

To create the shifting effect, I concatenated a list of each shifted piece.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("temp/df1.csv").drop_duplicates()
df2 = pd.read_csv("temp/df2.csv").drop_duplicates()

vlookuped = (df2.merge(df1, how="left", on=["Cal"])
             .drop(columns=["S.No", "Date"]))

result = (
    pd.concat([
        vlookuped,
        vlookuped.assign(DFM=lambda x: x["DFM"].shift(-1)),
        vlookuped.assign(DFM=lambda x: x["DFM"].shift(-2))],
        ignore_index=True)
    .fillna("100.00%"))
```

This code produces the following dataframe:

```
Cal    Group     DFM
  1 period 1  39.36%
  2 period 1  98.89%
  3 period 1  99.95%
  4 period 1  99.97%
  5 period 1  99.99%
  6 period 1 100.00%
  7 period 1 100.00%
  8 period 1 100.00%
  9 period 1 100.00%
 10 period 1 100.00%
  1 period 1  98.89%
  2 period 1  99.95%
  3 period 1  99.97%
  4 period 1  99.99%
  5 period 1 100.00%
  6 period 1 100.00%
  7 period 1 100.00%
  8 period 1 100.00%
  9 period 1 100.00%
 10 period 1 100.00%
  1 period 1  99.95%
  2 period 1  99.97%
  3 period 1  99.99%
  4 period 1 100.00%
  5 period 1 100.00%
  6 period 1 100.00%
  7 period 1 100.00%
  8 period 1 100.00%
  9 period 1 100.00%
 10 period 1 100.00%
```

Comment: Did you get the same output as I mentioned? Could you please print the output as well?

Comment: I've now added the output

Comment: There was a change so I edited my both dataframes and 3rd condition. Also I need different result. Could you check that please?

Comment: Also can you please try with df.join() as well. Thanks!!

Comment: The new use case simplified things a bit. I no longer am looping through S.No's at all. Using df.join() isn't a good fit for this use case, so I'd need to do something weird to find a way to shove it in.